# How to migrate a database from azure to another azure server?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, ssms

I want to migrate a database that I have in a windows azure server to another server in azure too.
I have exported the existing database to a .bacpac file, however when I try to import to the other server, also in azure, it fails.

I want to export schema and data. My database contain DataSync columns, but I don't want to export the DataSyncs.

Using the SQL Server Management Studio, this process fails too.

How can I do this?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server in VM, I think you can just backup/restore your database. If you are using SQL Azure, given that you failed using BACPAC, it might be working through Generate Script + BCP, which means you can generate your database schema from SQL Server Management Studio, export and import data using BCP. Both of them you can specify which tables you want to migrate so you can skip those `DataSync` stuffs.

Hope helps.

Comment: This was very helpfull.
This worked for me, but I found a problem in database too.
Thank you very much.